# Oracle11g: Improve performance of sum function and group by

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, group-by

I have this query:

```
    select CASE WHEN to_char(A.DATA_POSICAO_CARTEIRA, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20110513' 
THEN A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO ELSE A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO_ORIGINAL END  AS CODIGO_FAVORECIDO, '13/05/11' AS POSICAO_CARTEIRA, B.BANCO, B.AGENCIA, B.CONTA, 
sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_VENDA ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) +
sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_ANULACAO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) as VALOR_BRUTO,
sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_DESCONTO ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA_DESCONTO END, 0)) + sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_DESCONTO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA_DESCONTO END, 0)) as VALOR_COMISSAO, 
sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_VENDA ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) + sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_ANULACAO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) +        sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_DESCONTO ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA_DESCONTO END, 0)) + sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_DESCONTO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA_DESCONTO END, 0)) as VALOR_LIQUIDO,
                D.NOME_PRODUTO AS DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
                E.CNPJ_FAVORECIDO AS CNPJ,
                E.NOME_FAVORECIDO,
                G.CODIGO_EMPRESA_GRUPO,
                trunc(A.DATA_REPASSE_CALCULADA) as DATA_REPASSE_CALCULADA,
                G.DESCRICAO_EMPRESA_GRUPO
                from TB_TRANSACAO A
                left join TB_CONTA_FAVORECIDO B
                on B.CODIGO_CONTA_FAVORECIDO = CASE WHEN to_char(A.DATA_POSICAO_CARTEIRA, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20110513' THEN A.CODIGO_CONTA_FAVORECIDO ELSE A.CODIGO_CONTA_FAVORECIDO_ORIG END left join TB_TRANSACAO_VENDA TV
                    on A.CODIGO_TRANSACAO = TV.CODIGO_TRANSACAO
                    left join TB_TRANSACAO_ANULACAO_VENDA TAV
                    on A.CODIGO_TRANSACAO = TAV.CODIGO_TRANSACAO left join TB_ESTABELECIMENTO C
                on A.CODIGO_ESTABELECIMENTO = C.CODIGO_ESTABELECIMENTO
                left join TB_PRODUTO D
                on A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = D.CODIGO_PRODUTO
                left join TB_FAVORECIDO E
                on E.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO = CASE WHEN to_char(A.DATA_POSICAO_CARTEIRA, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20110513' THEN A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO ELSE A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO_ORIGINAL END
                left join TB_EMPRESA_SUBGRUPO F
                on C.CODIGO_EMPRESA_SUBGRUPO = F.CODIGO_EMPRESA_SUBGRUPO
                left join TB_EMPRESA_GRUPO G
                on F.CODIGO_EMPRESA_GRUPO = G.CODIGO_EMPRESA_GRUPO 
            WHERE A.TIPO_TRANSACAO IN ('CV', 'AV')  and A.STATUS_TRANSACAO <> 6 

             group by 
             CASE WHEN to_char(A.DATA_POSICAO_CARTEIRA, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20110513' THEN A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO ELSE A.CODIGO_FAVORECIDO_ORIGINAL END, '13/05/11', B.BANCO, B.AGENCIA, B.CONTA, D.NOME_PRODUTO,
                E.CNPJ_FAVORECIDO,
                E.NOME_FAVORECIDO,
                G.CODIGO_EMPRESA_GRUPO,
                A.DATA_REPASSE_CALCULADA,
                G.DESCRICAO_EMPRESA_GRUPO
                ORDER BY E.CNPJ_FAVORECIDO,
                E.NOME_FAVORECIDO,
                B.CONTA,
                B.AGENCIA,
                B.BANCO
```

This query is taking about 30s. When I removed the Sum functions, the time to return decreased to 9s. Even with the Group By.

I tried to remove the order by, create indexes. But didn't work

Any idea to improve the Sum function ?

Thanks

Ps: The type of the numeric columns are number(14,2)

Comment: Try to combine SUMs in each VALOR_* field in one SUM expression (i.e. SUM(nvl(smth, 0)) + SUM(nvl(smth_else, 0)) is equal to SUM(nvl(smth, 0) + nvl(smth_else, 0))).

Comment: I've tried to use only the sum(smth), without CASE or nvl. I think its all about the sum.

Comment: I understand, so my advice is about reducing a number of SUM calls in your query. For example, instead of `sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_VENDA ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) +
sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_ANULACAO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) as VALOR_BRUTO` you can write `sum(nvl(CASE WHEN TV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TV.VALOR_VENDA ELSE TV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0) +
nvl(CASE WHEN TAV.VALOR_PARCELA = 0 THEN TAV.VALOR_ANULACAO ELSE TAV.VALOR_PARCELA END, 0)) as VALOR_BRUTO`, which contains only one SUM call (versus two calls in your statement), etc

Comment: Your SELECT statement begins with `select state`. I've never seen `state` used in this context, nor could I find documentation of it in the Oracle 11.2 manual. Could you please explain this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry! It's wrong, the correct query is without "state". Even with only one Sum, its taking 30s. I have 2 million lines on TB_TRANSACAO. If I remove the Sum, works well.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the EXPLAIN PLAN output for your query, both with and without the SUM functions? Also, an explanation of the indexes on the tables involved would be helpful. Thanks.